# Access VB does not seem to read from the database

Tags: ms-access, vba

```
Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT role" & _
        " FROM EMP " & _
        " WHERE id =" & Chr(34) & id & Chr(34))

If rst.Fields(role) = "admin" Then
    cmdConnecterPrivilege.Visible = True
Else
    cmdConnecterPrivilege.Visible = False
End If
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks! I want to see if this employee is an admin

Comment: What exactly is going wrong?  Are you getting an error? What data type is `id`? It is difficult to help if you don't post the full details of the problem.

Comment: VB.NET is not access-vba.  Its doubtful the ID is a string, so & the quotes & might & confuse & it

Comment: @Fred you know access it gives me an exception and that's it, id is string

Comment: Yes I do know Access, it gives you details of the error/exception.  What are they?

Comment: What makes you think I am anything other than cool as a cucumber?  Since the tags include verbiage like "DO NOT USE THIS For xxxx" and you were oblivious to that sage guidance, I pointed it out.  Tags help you get help from those with expertise in that area; no VB.NET answer would help you,

Comment: @Fred Run Time Error 3265 - Item not found in this collection

Comment: Try `rst.Fields("role").value`

Comment: Using http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/3992/vba-option-keyword/13935/option-explicit would have prevented that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the right syntax, either of these:

```
If rst.Fields("role") = "admin"
If rst("role") = "admin"
If rst!role = "admin"
```

But you can use one code line for this simple task:

```
cmdConnecterPrivilege.Visible = (Nz(DLookup("role", "EMP", "ID = '" & id & "'")) = "admin")
```